# Reference to reference in rust

Tags: rust

```
fn count_occur(v: &Vec<i32>, val: i32) -> usize {
    v.into_iter().filter(|&&x| x == val).count()
}

fn main() -> () {
    let v1 : Vec<i32> = vec![1,2,3, 4,5,6];
    for &item in &v1 {
        count_occur(&v1, item);
    }  
}
```

Can someone explain me why does `lambda` need to take `&&x` (I mean why double reference is necessary - I cannot see why an element passed to the lambda is a reference to a reference)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-or

Comment: Btw: It is bad pratice to write `-> ()`, because returning the unit type is the default and you don't need to expliclty write it. See https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#unused_unit

Comment: There's a twist here not covered in the duplicate -- the resolution of the`into_iter()` method. There's a separate implementation of `IntoIterator` for `&Vec<T>`, which calls`iter()` on the vector, so the item type is `&T`.

Answer (score 0):

[IntoIterator implementation for &'a Vec](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec.rs.html#1777-1784) is returning items of `&T`.

[`filter`'s predicate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/adapters/mod.rs.html#681-735) is defined as `where P: FnMut(&I::Item) -> bool`. It's taking a reference to the iterator's item, hence the double reference.